# Подскажите с API QIWI PHP

Tags: php, api, qiwi

День добрый. Юзаю исходники из гитхаба по адресу : https://github.com/Shnapik/Qiwi-Api-Class-PHP.
Конструирую запрос в соответствии с примером автора

```
$sendMoney = $qiwi->sendMoneyToQiwi([
    'id' => '11111111111111',
    'sum' => [
        'amount'   => 1,
        'currency' => '643'
    ], 
    'paymentMethod' => [
        'type' => 'Account',
        'accountId' => '643'
    ],
    'comment' => 'Тестовый платеж',
    'fields' => [
        'account' => 'Номер получателя'
    ]
]);
```

и получаю в ответе:

```
Array ( [code] => QWPRC-309 [message] => Доступ запрещен )
```

Стучался в поддержку QIWI и ничего путного сказать они не могут..к слову, использовал cUrl с их документации и получал ту же самую ошибку. Может кто сталкивался ?

З.Ы -> Другие методы из исходников гитхаба работают на ура.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено. Достаточно отключить SMS подтверждение.